# hiding certain options in zsh autocompletion

Tags: zsh, tab-completion

There are several commands that have esoteric options that I don't use often.  For example, git has 'check-attr'.  I use 'git checkout' very often, however, so I'd like,
  git ch
to complete to
  git checkout
or show a menu without check-attr in it.  I can do this with zstyle ... ignored-patterns.

However, I'd still like to complete 'git check-attr' if nothing else matches (if I actually *do* want to run check-attr).

It seems that the 'hidden' zstyle is for me, but  how can I specify a value (not just a tag) in the completion context?  I.e. I'd like something like,
zstyle ':completion:*:*:git:*:*' hidden-patterns 'check-attr'

Is that possible?

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but you could obviously make `git ch` an alias of `git checkout`, which be good if you would just like to use `git checkout` without having to disambiguate with `git check-attr`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really know how this works, but the result is that `git check<TAB>` results in `git checkout`. Add this to your `.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion::complete:git:*:*' ignored-patterns 'check*-*'
```

See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Overview-1 for some info, if you can decypher it..

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
zstyle ':completion::complete:*:git:*' ignored-patterns check-attr
```